# Relative Strength Index Function Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a function that mimics the Relative Strength Index (RSI) that stock traders use to find data that deviates from a normal trend.  The equation for RSI is: 100 - (100/1+RS) where RS = X number of days above the cost center average/ X number of days below the cost center average.  Here is my code:

```
def RIS(A):
    X = cost_center_average(A)
    a = 0
    b = 0

    for i in range(len(X)):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            for k in range(len(A[i])):
                if A[j][0] in X[i]:
                    if A[j][k] > X[i][1]:
                        a = a + 1
                    else:
                        b = b + 1
                        RS = a/b
                        result = 100 - (100/(1+RS))
                        print A[j], result
                        break
```

Here are the helper functions (`cost_center_average`)('cost_center_sum')('mean'):

```
def cost_center_average(A):
    X = cost_center_sum(A)
    Y = []
    for i in range(len(X)):
        Y += [[X[i][0]]+ [mean(X[i][1:])]]
    return Y

NUMBER_OF_MONTHS = 12
def cost_center_sum(A):
dep = dict()
for row in A:
    if row[0] not in dep:
        dep[row[0]] = [0.0 for x in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS)]
    for i in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS):
        dep[row[0]][i] += row[i+2]
ret = list()
for department in sorted(dep.iterkeys()):
    x = [department]
    x.extend(dep[department])
    ret.append(x)
return ret


def mean(values):
"""Returns the mean.
"""
return sum(values)*1.0/len(values)
```

My input `A` is a list of lists where each inner list contains a cost center ID, employee ID, and monthly data.  I essentially want the function to match cost center IDs, count the number of overs (`a`) and unders (`b`), and then run the RSI equation.  My code must be wrong, however, because my output is the list `A[j]`, 80 for every single list.  There should be varying values for result, but for some reason the way I have written the code, it always returns a "result" of 80.  Does anyone know where I went wrong in my logic/code?

Sample Input:

```
[[136676.0, 12097.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334],[136710.0, 10273.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334],[136711.0, 10139.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334],[136712.0, 10271.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334],[136761.0, 10564.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.327274, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.545457],[136797.0, 10273.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334]]]
```

Sample Output:

```
[136676.0, 12097.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334] 80
[136710.0, 10273.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334] 80
[136711.0, 10139.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334] 80
[136712.0, 10271.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334] 80
[136761.0, 10564.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.327274, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.545457] 80
[136797.0, 10273.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333334] 80
```

P.S. I tested my `cost_center_average` helper function and it works correctly

Comment: Could you provide the helper function and example inputs and expected and actual outputs, so others can actually run this and see the problem? Also, is that the indentation you are actually using?

Comment: Just added it.  And yes all the indents are accurate of my actual code

Comment: And `cost_center_sum`? `mean`? Should you really be printing the result after the first under?

Comment: So do you think the error is because I have result printing under the else statement?

Comment: It certainly doesn't look right. It might be easier if you split this down into smaller, simpler functions. For example, start by writing one that just takes one row of monthly data and the corresponding average for the cost center, and returns the RSI for that one row. You can then easily test it and build out from there. Also, consider a dictionary, keyed by cost center, for your cost center averages.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indentation matters to how code is executed. For example:

```
if A[j][k] > X[i][1]:
  a = a + 1
else:
  b = b + 1
  RS = a/b
  result = 100 - (100/(1+RS))
  print A[j], result
  break
```

As soon as your code finds the FIRST A[j][k] that is below average, your code will perform the RS computation and then proceed to display the result and terminate. I could be misunderstanding your problem, but I do believe that this is not your desired behavior.

Comment: You're right.  I want it to go through the entire inner list before ending.  Should I move RS and the result values outside the loop then to avoid the early termination then?

Comment: That would be a good start. Whichever loop needs to be traversed in its entirety, you need to move your final calculations outside of that loop. I would also recommend following jonrsharpe's advice if you get more problems since your code will be much easier to debug that way.